# Auth0 angular2-jwt /node_modules/buffer/package.json 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular, auth0

When I follow steps from Auth0 docs (https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/08-calling-apis), I get this message :

```
GET http://localhost:5556/node_modules/buffer/package.json 404 (Not Found)

(index):50 Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading
```

Do you know how I can fix it ?

My project is built with : https://github.com/vyakymenko/angular2-seed-express

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buffer should be part of your node_modules. Look inside the node_modules folder for Buffer. If it is not there then you need to run 'npm install'.

Buffer wasnt introduce until after Node.js version 5.10.0 (info on buffer found [Here](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)) So you also want to make sure you are using a version greater than or equal to 5.10.0. Once you install an up to date version of node, you will once again need to run 'npm install' on your project.

As discussed in the comment you can also run the command `npm install buffer` if none of the above works

Comment: node version : 6.9.1. I don't have "buffer" in node_modules, I've also run "npm install" but I still get the same error ?

Comment: try running `npm install buffer` on your project

Comment: Also quick question, Are you using Visual studios to build this project?

Comment: No no I don"t use VS, why ?

Comment: nvm your all good, I will update my answer, mind accepting it?